# Flaky system test with Rails 5.1 and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I've been trying to debug this for days and just can't figure out what's the problem. I originally thought it was an order dependency, but I don't think so anymore and so `rspec --bisect=verbose`.

I now lean to either Devise/Warden helpers not working correctly, me not setting up capybara/web drivers correctly or something else.

This test **sometimes** fails:

1. On redirect, when selecting items from menu to redirect to another page. Like example `redirects to Account Settings page after pressing Account Settings`. This is where I blame Devise helpers, as I am logged in when I land on the home page, but `current_user` returns `nil` when I get to Account Settings, hence example fails as it is redirected to a login page.

This is also test specific, live code worked with no problems for months.

#### System Test

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'home page', type: :system do
  before(:context) do
    WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
  end

  after(:each) do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end

  context 'when not logged in' do
    it 'displays login with discord button' do
      visit '/'

      expect(page).to have_content 'Login with Discord'
    end

    it 'logs in with discord after clicking Login with Discord' do
      OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

      visit '/'

      click_on 'Login with Discord'

      expect(page).to_not have_content 'Login with Discord'

      find('.profile-menu').hover

      expect(page).to have_content 'Account Settings'
      expect(page).to have_content 'Event Calendar'
      expect(page).to have_content 'Logout'
    end
  end

  context 'when logged in' do
    context 'as an average user' do
      before do
        @user = build(:user, confirmed_at: Time.now)
        create(:profile, user: @user)

        login_as(@user, scope: :user)
      end

      it 'shows profile menu' do
        visit '/'

        find('.profile-menu').hover

        expect(page).to have_content 'Account Settings'
        expect(page).to have_content 'Event Calendar'
        expect(page).to have_content 'Logout'
      end

      it 'logs user out after pressing Logout' do
        visit '/'

        find('.profile-menu').hover
        find('.logout').click

        expect(page).to have_content 'Login with Discord'
      end

      it 'redirects to Events page after pressing Event Calendar' do
        event = create(:event)

        visit '/'

        find('.profile-menu').hover
        find('.event-calendar').click

        expect(page).to have_content event.title
      end

      it 'redirects to Account Settings page after pressing Account Settings' do
        visit '/'

        find('.profile-menu').hover
        find('.settings').click

        expect(page).to have_content 'Account Settings'
      end
    end

    context 'as an organiser' do
      before do
        @user = build(:user, confirmed_at: Time.now, role: :organiser)
        create(:profile, user: @user)

        login_as(@user, scope: :user)
      end

      it 'shows profile menu with Organiser Dashboard link' do
        visit '/'

        find('.profile-menu').hover

        expect(page).to have_content 'Organiser Dashboard'
      end

      it 'redirects to Organiser Dashboard page after pressing Organiser Dashboard' do
        visit '/'

        find('.profile-menu').hover
        find('.organiser-dashboard').click

        expect(page).to have_content 'Create Event'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### Devise configuration

```
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
end
```

#### Javascript driving menu redirection

```
handleCommand(command) {
  if (command === "logout") {
    Rails.ajax({
      url: "/sign_out",
      type: "DELETE",
      dataType: "json",
      success: (signed_in_status) => {
        this.$store.commit('authenticate', false)
        this.$message.success('You logged out');
        location.href = "/";
      },
      error: (signed_in_status) => {
        this.$store.commit('authenticate', true)
        this.$message.error('Something went wrong');
      }
    })
  }
  else if (command === "settings") {
    location.href = "/users/edit";
  }
  else if (command === "events") {
    location.href = "/events";
  }
  else if (command === "organiser") {
    location.href = "/admin/events";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `@user` actually getting saved during the `create(:profile, user: @user)` call? if not then it wouldn't be a loadable from the DB after the redirect.  Also, what versions of Rails and Capybara are you using?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I am sure it is, `current_user` is set when I do `visit '/'`. I checked that the User is still there on the redirect, yet `current_user` is `nil`

Comment: Is the project publicly accessible so I can run the test?

Comment: What do you have for account_settings/devise setup? is something just getting temporarily lost along the way? Secondly: can you try something other than your `before/after :all`s? Say try mocking out the specific relevant method-calls, just to rule that out as the issue? I'm wondering if `test_reset!` could be cleaning up warden with odd timing and cleaning out `current_user` after the redirect for some weird internal reason...

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I am afraid not, do you mind telling what you were thinking of trying?

Comment: @TarynEast I've tried to run only one test, to see if I can access Account Settings. No before/after blocks, just setting Webmock and user to login. I also didn't do `Warden.test_reset!`. Test failed 1/4 times

Comment: @TarynEast `account_settings` is standard devise `Users::RegistrationsController#edit`. I have some custom actions in there, but this specific link just calls `super`

Comment: @MaximFedotov Nothing really specific, just look around to see if any configuration settings jump out, add sleeps between each of the steps to see if that improves the reliability, etc.  The fact that it only sometimes fails is strange because nothing in the "Account Settings" test should really be timing dependent unless you're lazy loading the JS behavior or screwing with the session cookie in JS

Comment: Did the sleeps change the likelihood of failure significantly?

Comment: note: we eventually implemented a "wait for ajax" method which checks if any scripts are running and slept until they all finished... for similar reasons.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Well I've been trying different combinations and I don't think it's the test configuration. I might be not setting up capybara correctly? I used default settings. I was also trying to see what could be affecting session cookies, but not sure how to debug. `current_user` is always present on the first-page load, so if I go to, say Account Settings, page directly, its there. It's on redirect that it is lost.

Comment: @TarynEast I don't think the waits affects the redirect. I've actually started to use waits on a different test due to animations screwing with capybara clicks. But I am planning to just disable animations all together in testing to avoid having to do that. But I don't feel like waiting would help with redirects losing the `current_user`

Comment: @MaximFedotov The first request would always work because `login_as` short-circuits the login for 1 request and sets the logged in user object directly.  That's why I asked if `@user` was actually being saved because on the second request it has to do a real lookup based on the session cookie set during the first response.  The issue is you say the failure is intermittent which tends to indicate timing issues.  Did you actually try sleeping for a few seconds between each step and see if it makes the test reliable? (you say you don't think it affects, but did you actually try?)

Comment: @MaximFedotov Also, everyone always says they "used default settings" but then it turns out they've turned off transactions, aren't actually letting Capybara run the AUT, or are doing some custom session management, etc, etc.  That's why I asked if it was publicly accessible because it's usually just easier to take a look through the whole test config than trying to piecemeal together what people report they've configured.  If you can put together a minimal example that shows the behavior it would make this much easier (and probably lead you to find the cause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this issue. I've tried a couple things mentioned in this SO answer. As far as I can tell, what fixed it was fixing my configuration from:

```
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
 end
```

to

```
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :system
 end
```

This also allowed me to drop:

```
  after(:each) do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
```

in all my tests. I've run quite a few tests and they don't fail anymore, so I am for now assuming this has been indeed fixed.

Comment: Did this fix continue to work? I seem to have the same issue (except with React) but unfortunately this doesn't work for me. It still is flaky - fails maybe 10-20% of the time.